# How to add a comment to an existing column with Laravel migrations?

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration

I have a table in my MySQL database with some existing columns. I would like to add a comment to one of these columns using Laravel migrations to provide additional information about its purpose.

I understand that I can add comments to new columns when creating a migration using the [comment() method](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#:%7E:text=%2D%3Ecomment(%27my%20comment%27)). However, I'm not sure how to add a comment to an existing column.

Can someone please provide an example of how to modify an existing column in a Laravel migration to add a comment to it? For example, I want to add a comment to the `email` column in my `users` table.

The database already exists, and I would like to apply the migration without recreating part of it, just updating it.

Answer (score 1):

See document:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#modifying-columns

creating migration file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('name', 255)->comment('comment added')->change();
        });
    }
};
```

then

```
php artisan migrate
```

comment would be added:

```
mysql> show full columns from users;
+-------------------+---------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------------+
| Field             | Type                | Collation          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          | Privileges                      | Comment       |
+-------------------+---------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------------+
| id                | bigint(20) unsigned | NULL               | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | select,insert,update,references |               |
| name              | varchar(255)        | utf8mb4_unicode_ci | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references | comment added |
| email             | varchar(255)        | utf8mb4_unicode_ci | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |               |
| email_verified_at | timestamp           | NULL               | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |               |
| password          | varchar(255)        | utf8mb4_unicode_ci | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |               |
| remember_token    | varchar(100)        | utf8mb4_unicode_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |               |
| created_at        | timestamp           | NULL               | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |               |
| updated_at        | timestamp           | NULL               | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |               |
+-------------------+---------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------------+
8 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Wouldn't this code "recreate" the column? It looks like you are defining it again (with the datatype and char length). Isn't there a way of adding a column without redefining the data type?

Comment: It's not recreating. I checked it won't be deleted on my local environment.

Comment: @Kotapom but mistakes can be easily made if the specified data type is different from the actual one. This is highly probable, specially if the table has not been created using Laravel migrations...

Comment: @GuillemPoy I suggested to add migration file because your question was in context of Laravel. If you hesitate to do so, how about modify the tables directy by SQL?

Comment: I am updating an already existing database, and to have continuous deployment, we use Laravel migrations, since they can consistently apply changes to a database. Specially important having an alpha, beta and production environment.

Comment: It is not possible to add a column with existing name even if its type is different from original one.

Comment: I am talking about adding a comment to an already existing column without "redefining" its type

Comment: I got your point, but have no solution for your concern.

Comment: @GuillemPoy Just use definition which is already set to the column. If it is `text`, use text and so on.

Answer (score 0):

first you require doctrine/dbal package install using below command

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

then create migration for making changes

```
php artisan make:migration add_comment_to_email_column_in_users_table
```

make changes in the created migration file

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->string('email')->unique()->comment('email')->change();
});
```

then run

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: This way, it looks like I am defining the data type again. Isn't there a way to identify the table without setting a data type?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function up() {
  Schema::table('product', function (Blueprint $table) { 
    $table->string('product_type')
        ->comment('0 = A Industrial Products, 1 = A Consumer Products')
        ->change();
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a way of adding a column without redefining the data type?